# 404 error when templateUrl is a php file in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, woocommerce, ionic-framework

I am building a mobile application for my woocommerce website using ionic framework. I included home page template with Url stateProvider like this:

```
.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'http://example.com/wp-content/themes/app/templates/home.php',
        }
    }
})
```

home.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once('../../../../wp-blog-header.php');
require_once('../../../plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php');
require_once('../../../plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/init.php');
echo 'Test Content';
// Image slider, product list etc future work.
```

But it gives 404 error [(Link)](http://pasteboard.co/34NEqSy.jpg). Same url works if entered directly in browser [(Link)](http://pasteboard.co/36jwZzG.jpg).

I tried using html template and it works correctly. But that requires woocommerce api and custom api for other plugins. (It is not required if php file works directly)

How can we include php file directly as template?

Answer (score 0):

You can include a php file that returns a html template in templateUrl property with Content Type text/html.

In fact I faced the same issue, and when I included the php API returning a template it worked fine with "ionic serve" on browser.

But after creating an apk and running it on phone, it gave a 404 error.

To resolve this you need to add cordova whitelist plugin, type following on your ionic project root command line:

**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist**

Also make sure you have cordova **android@4.0.0** or above for the plugin to work.

then make sure root config.xml contains `<access origin="*"/>`

and you can add following meta tag in your index.html.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Follow the above and it will certainly help you.

Comment: Followed. Still it gives 404. Both before and after building apk